# Error writing output file 'int' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python

I an new to Python, trying to overwrite the last 128 bytes of a file with zer0s. What am I doing wrong?

```
   try:
      f = open(outputFile, "wb")

      for x in range(1, 128):
         f.seek(x, 2)   # seek relative to end of file
         f.write(0)

      f.close()

   except Exception as e:
      sys.exit('Error writing output file ' + str(e)) 

Error writing output file 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

---

[Update]

this runs with no error, but the zer0s are not written (I mean `\0` (end of string))

```
  f = open(outputFile, "rb+")

  zeros = bytearray(0 * 128)
  f.seek(-128, 2)   # seek relative to end of file
  f.write(zeros)

  f.close()
```

Note: when I tried `f.write('\0'*128)` I got `Error writing output file 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: Just typecast  int 0 to string like this str(0).

Comment: you should just use `bytearray(128)` to get the array of NULs

Comment: If you are using python3, you'd need to use `b'\0'*128` to make a `bytes` object

Comment: Did you get it working? To clarify `bytearray(0 * 128)` is same as `bytearray(0)` ie. empty `bytearray`. Writing that would have no effect of course!

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks, you can post an answer. However, I have a new problem which I will address in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean NUL bytes

```
f.write('\0')
```

If you want actual zeros

```
f.write('0')
```

If you mean to overwrite just the last part of the file (as opposed to append)

```
with open('x', 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-128, 2)
    f.write('\0'*128)
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work :=(  What is wrong with the updated code?

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
f.write(0)
```

to:

```
f.write(str(0))
```

you need to convert it to type `str`