# Write to the end of a binary file

Tags: python

I an new to Python, trying to overwrite the last 128 bytes of a file with zer0s. What am I doing wrong?

```
   try:
      f = open(outputFile, "wb")
      f.seek(128, 2)   # seek relative to end of file
      f.write(b'\0'*128)
      f.close()

   except Exception as e:
      sys.exit('Error writing output file ' + str(e))
```

It runs fine, but my 2mB file is truncated to 256 bytes, all zer0.

Comment: You appear to be seeking 128 bytes *past* the end of the file. `help (file.seek)` says seeking relative to the end of the file should be a negative number. I don't know why this is resulting in a truncated file, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), opening in `'w'` mode truncates the file (i.e., erases its existing contents).  Try opening it in `'r+b'` mode.

Also, as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) (although admittedly not with total clarity), seeks relative to the end of the file still use positive numbers meaning "forward" and negative meaning "backward" (i.e., towards the beginning of the file).  You are seeking past the end of the file.  Use `seek(-128, 2)`.

Comment: which is what we were doing in his [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986918/error-writing-output-file-int-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface/26986961#26986961). I guess something got lost in translation